# CRM 2016 for outlook connected privilege error

Tags: dynamics-crm

After installation of CRM for outlook, connection prompt error message

> Principal user (Id=e1d4caec-db31-e611-80be-00155d036d5c, type=8) is missing prvReadRole privilege (Id=222a920a-2778-4564-85cb-e78dde8e4276)

Answer (score 1):

As the message says, the user is missing the `prvReadRole` privilege. This can be assigned in: *Settings->Security->Security Roles->Choose specific role->Business Management->Read*.

As a side-note, you might encounter other missing privileges. A best practice is to use the out of the box security roles (e.g. by making a copy and saving your own modifications in the copied role).